# How to Filter Websites on Local Computer?

Tags: networking, server, proxy, websites, dansguardian

I want to filter websites on my local ubuntu Desktop 14.04.

I don't have a dedicated server to configure dansguardian on with two *NICs just one desktop*.

I tried flowing some tutorials with **dansguardian** but they are all for **dedicated filtering machines** **i only have one computer**, so i cant quite accomplish what i need by those ,i tried but somethings is going wrong.**So my question is how do i filter websites in my local and only computer**,*and don't even say opendns ,tell a linux approach.Oh i don't know if its relevant but*

**i have squid3 configured with basic_ncsa_auth program with htpasswd as caching proxy and bind9 as caching nameserver** , **why you ask ?** *cause im poor thats why and my INTERNET is slow,so i speed it up that way a bit.*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by filtering? If you have a specific list of websites you want to block, you could either directly edit your /etc/hosts file, or you could use a program like PeerGuardian and create your own blocklist.

Comment: Block porn sites all of them like dansguardian list

Comment: What if you create a virtualbox vm with bridged adapter and static ip to configure dansguardian?, spare 512mb or ram for it, make it run on boot, and filter your content through it. Also, you can put squid and bind there too.

Comment: Thats the first thing i thought of.but too much resource consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to block porn on a single computer, PeerGuardian should suit your needs. Just install the software, and add the Porn blocklist.

Installation: http://sourceforge.net/p/peerguardian/wiki/pgl-Install-DebianUbuntu/

Blocklists: https://www.iblocklist.com/lists